# Is there a easy way to switch between asp.net 5beta5 and asp.net 5beta6.

Tags: asp.net-core

When I Switch to the nightly builds.

https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/

My beta5 ptojects will get errors because it sees the latest nuget package which are in compatible with the beta5.

The solution now is:
turnoff the nightly build and remove all packages in the global nuget cache and rebuild everything again.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose beta5 packages on your project.json like "beta5-*" when you dnu restore, it will download beta5 even if it finds beta6 packages.

you also want to specify on global.json the beta5 sdk.

that way, you can keep your nightly feed and run beta5 and beta6 projects with no errors.